# Complex records and private default property

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, records

I have a following record:

```
type
  TMongoIdArray = array[0..11] of Byte;

  TMongoId = record
  strict private
    FMongoIdArray: TMongoIdArray;

    function GetMongoIdByte(Index: Integer): Byte;
    procedure SetMongoIdByte(Index: Integer; const Value: Byte);
    function GetMemory: pointer;

    property MongoIdArray[Index: Integer]: Byte read GetMongoIdByte
        write SetMongoIdByte; default;
  public
    class operator Implicit(const AMongoId: TMongoIdArray): TMongoId;
    class operator Implicit(const APointer: pointer): TMongoId;
    class operator Implicit(const AVariant: Variant): TMongoId;
    class operator Implicit(const AString: String): TMongoId;
    class operator Equal(const AMongoId1, AMongoId2: TMongoId): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const AMongoId1, AMongoId2: TMongoId): Boolean;

    function ToDateTime: TDateTime;
    function ToVariant: Variant;
    function ToString: String;
    function IsEmpty: Boolean;
    procedure Clear;

    property Memory: pointer read GetMemory;
  end;
```

I don't want user to see `MongoIdArray` property when trying to access record methods/properties **outside of this unit**, and solved this by putting default property in `strict private` section. Is this common (and recommended) practice?

**Update from comments**

I'm asking if its common practice to put default property under private/strict private to hide it from being accessed anywhere in the code (not only local unit).

Comment: How else are you going to control visibility?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't ask. Just first time using/seeing properties declared under `private` section, so it looked weird at first glance.

Comment: I don't understand the question then. Do you want to know what `private` and `strict private` mean? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I'm asking if its common practice to put default property under `private`/`strict private` to hide it from being accessed *anywhere* in the code. (not only local unit). But I uguess there is no other way of doing other than declaring property under `private`/`strict private` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking if its common practice to put default property under private/strict private to hide it from being accessed anywhere in the code (not only local unit).

The [visibility specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members) (`private` and `strict private` are visibility specifiers) are the only way to control which symbols can be seen by the rest of your program. So, it's not so much whether or not this is common practice, rather there is simply no other way to do this.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know, thank you. Feel free to edit my question if you can rephrase it better, I had hard time explaining what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between `private` and `strict private` is that `private` members are visible to all objects and methods in the same unit while `strict private` members are only visible within the class or record itself.

If your only concern is to hide the underlying field from consumers outside the class then simply `private` is sufficient.

Comment: I know how to hide it, I was just curious if this is common practice, to put default property inside `private`/`strict private`, so it's not visible outside of unit scope, or there is some more appropriate solution for this. But I guess there are no many options left, based on your answer.

Comment: @J... that's a record.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Of course - I think I've reminded myself of that twice already and have promptly forgotten it moments later.  No problems, then, I think.  For a class, marking it `sealed` would also probably be fine if inheritance was problematic.

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic: It is not common practice, and the only reason I see to do this is easy of writing, i.e. for you, it may be simpler to write `MongoIDArray[0] := 17;` than `SetMongoIDByte(0, 17);` Otherwise I don't see an advantage and that is why it is probably not done very often.